# HTML in createNotice with Gutenberg shows [object Object]

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I’m playing around with creating a custom notice in Gutenberg, and based on whether the data validates when the post is saved, the notice may include some HTML links.

I ended up only seeing the raw HTML output, so after some searching on Google I found [this post](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/6292#issuecomment-382851504) on Github suggesting to use RawHTML.

So I put this code together which does create the red notice, but it doesn’t show the actual HTML only [object Object]. So I’m clearly doing something wrong here, but not sure what? Anyone who can point me in the right direction how to make the notices show the raw HTML?

```
wp.data.dispatch( 'core/notices' ).createNotice(
   'error',
   wp.element.createElement( wp.element.RawHTML, null, '<p>test</p>' ),
   {
      id: 'wpslupdate', // prevent duplicates
      isDismissible: true
   }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The [notice component](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/data/data-core-notices/) has an [actions property](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/2224d4f59892aec92718c0e9a48866d28967156d/packages/components/src/notice/README.md#props) which enables links to be rendered inside a notice, removing the need to use RawHTML.

> options.actions [Array]: User actions to be presented with notice.

A notice can have one or more actions, each action has a label and must specify either a url or onClick function, eg:

```js
wp.data.dispatch('core/notices').createNotice(
    'error', // type of notice
    'Something went wrong..', // message
    {
        id: 'wpslupdate', // prevent duplicates
        isDismissible: true,
        actions: [
            {
                label: 'Option A',
                url: '#link' // styled as plain link
            },
            {
                label: 'Option B',
                onClick: () => { alert('ok') } // styled as a button link
            }
        ]
    }
);
```

Result:
[image: Error notice with action links]